# Script to put image behind music?

Tags: shell, audio, crop

I have some .mp3, or .m4a file, and I want to download an image from the internet (given some URL), then make a video, the same # of seconds long as the music file but with the image behind it.

If the image is not to scale (i.e. I need 1920x1080 but the image is 1920x1920), I want to just chop off from the bottom and right edges until the resolution matches. Is there a simple programmatic way to do this? I would like a command line tool like ffmpeg so that I can easily just change a few lines in the code and have it overlay a different image on a different song.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887311/ffmpeg-1-image-1-audio-file-1-video . It shows how to combine an image with an audio file with ffmpeg.

For manipulating images you should take a look at netpbm. This is a package of tools that convert and manipulate images on the command line.

With netbpm tools you could do something like:

```
wget -O somefile1.jpg http://where.ever/somefile.jpg
jpegtopnm somefile1.jpg > somefile2.pnm
pnmcut -left 0 -top 0 -width 1920 -height 1080 somefile2.pnm > somefile3.pnm
pnmtojpeg somefile3.pnm > somefile4.jpg
```

or shorter:

```
wget -O somefile1.jpg http://where.ever/somefile.jpg
jpegtopnm somefile1.jpg | \
pnmcut -left 0 -top 0 -width 1920 -height 1080 | \
pnmtojpeg > somefile4.jpg
```